# Apache Ignite query not retrieving for Cache fields configured in CacheTypeMetadata

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I have configured a Datagrid Cache in apache ignite. the query fields are configured using `CacheTypeMetada`. 
But I cannot retrieve the values from the Cache using sql.

If I change the query fields configured to `@QueryIndexType (index = true)`
The query returns result.

My question is, is there any config I am missing to do sql query lookup into Cache configured using CacheTypeMetadata ?

Thankyou.

Providing my code snippet.

`CacheConfiguration<TestKey, Test> testCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(TEST_CACHE);`

The query firlds are configured using CacheTypeMetadata.

```
private static Collection<CacheTypeMetadata> testCacheMetadata(){
        Collection<CacheTypeMetadata> types = new ArrayList<>();
        CacheTypeMetadata type  = new CacheTypeMetadata();
        type.setKeyType(TestKey.class.getName());
        type.setValueType(Test.class.getName());
        Map<String, Class<?>> qryFlds = type.getQueryFields();

        qryFlds.put("testId", int.class);
        qryFlds.put("orgId", String.class);
        qryFlds.put("md5", String.class);

        Map<String, Class<?>> ascFlds = type.getAscendingFields();
        ascFlds.put("testId", int.class);
        ascFlds.put("orgId", String.class);

        types.add(type);
        return types;
    }
```

Query called :

```
private static void sqlQuery(Ignite ignite, TestKey testKey) {
        IgniteCache<TestKey, Test> cache = Ignition.ignite().cache(TEST_CACHE);

        // SQL clause 
        String sql = "where testId = ? and orgId = ?";


        // Execute query
        System.out.println("query result" +
                cache.query(new SqlQuery<TestKey, Test>(Test.class, sql).
                        setArgs(testKey.getTestId(), testKey.getOrgId())).getAll());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine for me. Can you take a look at my code and see if there is any difference from yours (see link below)?

https://github.com/vkulichenko/ignite-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vk/ignite/query/metadata1/Main.java

What version are you on?

Comment: Hi Valentin, 
Thanks for testing out the code. I am checking it against mine now. 
I am using ignite 1.0.0

Comment: Hi Valentin, I ran the same code on my system, still it returns null array, is there any config file I am missing?

Comment: I changed my version of Ignite to 1.1.0-incubating. And now query is retrieving the results.